# Performance problems with EF core QueryFilter

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

In our system we ran into performance problems while using QueryFilters in EF core.
The problem is that EF core filters inside a LEFT JOIN instead of doing the filtering outside of it.

The generated SQL looks something like this:

```
SELECT [pom].[Id],
        [pom].[DeleteDate],
        [pom].[UpdateDate],
        [pom].[Version],
        [t].[Id],
        [t].[MandatorId],
        [t].[NetPriceAmount],
        [t].[NetPriceCurrencyIso4217Code]
FROM [externaldata].[PurchaseOfferMetadata] AS [pom]
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [po].[Id],
            [po].[MandatorId],
            [po].[NetPriceAmount],
            [po].[NetPriceCurrencyIso4217Code]
    FROM [externaldata].[PurchaseOffer] AS [po]
    WHERE [po].[MandatorId] = 1
) AS [t] ON [pom].[Id] = [t].[Id]
WHERE [pom].[Id] IN 
    (CAST(3094411 AS bigint), 
    CAST(4757070 AS bigint), 
    CAST(4757112 AS bigint), 
    CAST(5571232 AS bigint))
```

The problematic part is `WHERE [po].[MandatorId] = 1`.
If this would be in the second `WHERE` statement, the query runs much faster.

The database model is configured like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseOffer>()
      .HasQueryFilter(po => po.MandatorId == 1)
      .ToTable(nameof(PurchaseOffer), schema: ExternalDataSchemaName);

modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseOfferMetadata>()
      .HasOne(pom => pom.PurchaseOffer)
      .WithOne(po => po.Metadata)
      .HasForeignKey<PurchaseOffer>(po => po.Id);
```

On the database we have set the foreign key like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[externaldata].[FK_PurchaseOffer_PurchaseOfferMetadata]', 'F') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [externaldata].[PurchaseOffer] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PurchaseOffer_PurchaseOfferMetadata] FOREIGN KEY
    (
        [Id]
    )
    REFERENCES [externaldata].[PurchaseOfferMetadata] ([Id])
END;
```

The EF core query looks like this:

```
var existingPurchaseOfferMetadatasById = await db.PurchaseOfferMetadatas
   .Where(pom => purchaseOfferIds.Contains(pom.Id))
   .Include(pom => pom.PurchaseOffer)
   .ToDictionaryAsync(pom => pom.Id, cancellationToken);
```

Currently we have the following amount of records in each table:

- PurchaseOfferMetadata: 12'654'639
- PurchaseOffer: 1'689'634

Has anyone also encountered this problem and might found a solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Query Plan re-compilation when using IEnumerable.Contains in Entity Framework LINQ queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228362/how-to-avoid-query-plan-re-compilation-when-using-ienumerable-contains-in-entity)

Comment: EF issued exactly the query you were writing in your LINQ statement. .Include() also has to include those parents who do not have children, so it will always do a left outer join (and the right table has the filter as a "base" filter on it).It sounds like you want to do an inner join instead, which, you will notice, also filter out the parents without children, in which case you'll be good advised to specify it, i.e. by using the .Join function (INNER join), or specify the additional filter on the parent data set.

Comment: You've used a query filter on the po table `.HasQueryFilter(po => po.MandatorId == 1)` which will be applied everywhere that PurchaseOrder table is referenced, as it is referenced. If you remove that QueryFilter and instead add the where clause in your query, that should better optimize the query. If you're using a repository pattern or the like to manage your data retrieval I'd consider putting those low level conditions there rather than the model builder. The context model builder is more of a guarantee, but I suspect will lead to performance issues in the sake of conformity.

Comment: @StevePy We did exactly what you said and it improved the performance significantly. Still the queries are not perfect and we are looking for other ideas to improve the performance. EF core 3.0 might introduce some optimizations: [EF Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/features)

Comment: The first and foremost performance improvement you can make with EF is to leverage `.Select()` to populate simpler view models from your entity graph rather than pulling back entities and their related bits. (either lazy loaded Select N+1 traps, or even eager loaded)  Selecting less data means less memory on server, less data over the wire, and allows you to better tune indexing for common operations. For overly complex models such as report-like scenarios you can bind entities to materialized views to keep the code simple and the complexity in the database.

Answer (score 1):

EF has historically not done a great job of creating the most optimized SQL queries when joins are complex.  I can't answer how you get Linq to understand your database optimization design; however, if you know the SQL that should be generated, then I am proposing that for better complex READ performance, use a NuGet package like [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) to write the exact SQL you want and get the joins your database deserves.

```
using Dapper;

[...]

public class SalsaZima
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string MySalsaColumn { get; set; }
  public string MyZimaColumn { get; set; }
}

[...]

// get data from database
using (IDbConnection dp = Dapper)
{
  string query = @"SELECT 
                     s.ID
                    ,s.MySalsaColumn
                    ,z.MyZimaColumn
                   FROM dbo.Salsa s 
                   LEFT JOIN dbo.Zima z
                     ON s.ZimaID = z.ID";

  return dp.Query<SalsaZima>(query).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569749/why-entity-framework-performs-faster-than-dapper-in-direct-select-statement

Comment: If you choose Dapper, you can still use EF and Linq in simpler scenarios.  I only use Dapper where the joins get complicated and read performance is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `WHERE [po].[MandatorId] = 1` into the left outer join is correct, because putting `WHERE [po].[MandatorId] = 1` in the outer select, turns the left outer join into an inner join.
The question then becomes, do you really need left outer join, or inner join on the query.