# How can I intercept the ModelBuilder instance in a DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm writing a library that's going to provide new APIs around the `DbContext` class in Entity Framework Core 5+. I already have a version of these new APIs working, but it requires manual intervention in the final `DbContext` implementation, e.g.:

```
// Code in the library.
public static class AwesomeExtensions
{
    public static ModelBuilder AddAwesomeExtensionsSupportingEntities(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Set up custom entities I need to make this work.
        return modelBuilder;
    }
}

// Code somewhere else.
public class MyBusinessDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // I would like to avoid doing this here.
        modelBuilder.AddAwesomeExtensionsSupportingEntities();

        // Business as usual (database entities).
    }
}
```

After an extended search I haven't found an extension point in the EF Core API that allows me to do this in a non-intrusive way.

This is what I have found so far:

- CustomDbContext class: I could inherit from `DbContext` and override the `OnModelCreating` method, but this is not superior to what I'm doing right now.
- `DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseModel`: I thought this may be something I could use but adds too much complexity. By using this API the `OnModelCreating` method won't be called by the framework.
- `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>`: I was rooting for this one but it also requires you to have access to the `ModelBuilder` instance, then you can use the `ModelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` method.

Ideally, I would like to do this via the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` object provided when registering the `DbContext` dependency, e.g.:

```
// Code in some application.
public void AddServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyBusinessDbContext>(options =>
    {
        // The ideal solution.
        options.UseAwesomeExtensions();
    });
}
```

If I could only intercept the instance of the `ModelBuilder` just before it is provided to the `OnModelCreating` method, in a way that does not requires the modification of the `DbContext` implementation, that would help me.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/pYhe-Mt0HzI) by the EF Core team provides good insights relevant to this question (around 01:03:00).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF Core service responsible for calling `OnModelCreating` is called [`IModelCustomizer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.imodelcustomizer?view=efcore-5.0) with single method

> ```cs
> public void Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context);
> ```

Intercepting that method allows you to do what you need. The only problem is that EF Core does not provide an easy way to *override* existing implementation. The only available method is [`ReplaceService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder-1.replaceservice?view=efcore-5.0) which is all or nothing, with the obvious drawback that if you want to just perform pre/post processing of the base implementation, you need to know which is the class you are replacing. And of course some other extension can replace your implementation as well (last wins).

Implementing that correctly requires a bunch of boilerplate for registering custom [`IDbContextOptionsExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.idbcontextoptionsextension?view=efcore-5.0) to be able to manipulate directly services collection inside [`ApplyServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.idbcontextoptionsextension.applyservices?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_IDbContextOptionsExtension_ApplyServices_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_) method. If you are interested, you can find examples in other EF Core extension libraries (for instance, LinqKit).

Assuming no other extension is overriding the service in question, and knowing that the default EF Core implementation currently is provided by the [`ModelCustomizer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.modelcustomizer?view=efcore-5.0) class in general or [`RelationalModelCustomizer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.relationalmodelcustomizer?view=efcore-5.0) class for relational database (but currently doesn't add anything to the base implementation which simply calls `OnModelCreating`), the simplified implementation is a matter of inheriting one of these and replacing the service with your implementation. e.g. something like

```cs
namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    using Infrastructure;

    public static class AwesomeDbContextOptionsExtensions
    {
        public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseAwesomeExtensions(
            this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IModelCustomizer, AwesomeModelCustomizer>();
    }
}

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure
{
    public class AwesomeModelCustomizer : RelationalModelCustomizer
    {
        public AwesomeModelCustomizer(ModelCustomizerDependencies dependencies)
            : base(dependencies) { }
        public override void Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
        {
            // Do something before context.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)...
            base.Customize(modelBuilder, context);
            // Do something after context.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very useful. I'll give it a try and post back my results. I'll also take a look at LinqKit. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I decided to go with the correct approach that involves the `IDbContextOptionsExtension` interface. I can use the code in [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/ExpandableDbContextOptionsExtension.cs) as a starting point for mine.

Comment: btw @Ivan! How did you know about `IModelCustomizer`? is there a place in the EF docs for extension authors?

Comment: Most of the things I know about EFC are from experimenting / traversing the source code. Regarding docs, if such place exists I would like to see it as well :)

Comment: Hi @Ivan. Just to let you know that your help with this question allowed me to create a [solution for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70587979/2206145). Thanks again!

Comment: @yv989c Great! So you are doing something similar to [EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin](https://github.com/neisbut/EntityFramework.MemoryJoin), but  for `Contains` and using different approach for passing the values.

Comment: Yes regarding solving the same kind of problem (composing local data with db data) but the strategy used in QueryableValues does not causes SQL Server plan cache pollution which MemoryJoin badly does due to its lack of query parameterization. It's also fair to say that QueryableValues is a solution specialized for SQL Server and MemoryJoin aims to support different db technologies AFAIK.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, I'm wondering if [this](https://youtu.be/pYhe-Mt0HzI?t=3910) is the proper way of doing the service replacement. I'll explore this when I get a chance.

Comment: Hi @yv989c Negative,  they just explain their implementation of building their internal service provider, and replaced services there are the ones you specify via `ReplaceService`. But as I explained in the answer, this way you can only completely replace existing service, you can't get the original and use delegation. Also as I wrote, you can see sample implementation in LinqKit written by [Svyatoslav Danyliv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10646316/svyatoslav-danyliv) - see ...

Comment: ... [here](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/ExpandableDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.cs) and [here](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/ExpandableDbContextOptionsExtension.cs)

Comment: Hi @Ivan, you're right. My bad, I was watching the video and posted this comment without reviewing your answer. Thanks for the reply.