# Error CS1929 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#

> Error CS1929  'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and
> the best extension method overload
> 'Queryable.Contains<int?>(IQueryable<int?>, int?)' requires a receiver
> of type 'IQueryable<int?

once i try to run the code this error comes out , i dont know how to fix it.
this is the code

```
public void SendModelPallet(string IDs, StorageContext db)
{
    int[] ids = ViewModelsUtils.processIDs(IDs);
    PalletBoxes = db.ExternStoragePlaces.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.PalletPlaceID)).ToList();
    this.db = db;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ids.Any(item => item = c.PalletPlaceID)`

Comment: Does `ids.Contains(c.PalletPlaceID ?? int.MinValue)` compile?

Comment: Is `c.PalletPlaceID` an `int` or an `int?`  or something else ? if `int?`, see mjwills' comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if list contains item from other list in EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641016/check-if-list-contains-item-from-other-list-in-entityframework)

Comment: int? but it doesn't compile , @mjwills

Comment: int? but it doesn't compile @Pac0

Comment: Maybe Linq to SQL from EF has problems with null coalescing operator. 

Can you try using int?[] for your array instead ?

Comment: Does `ids.Contains((int)(c.PalletPlaceID ?? int.MinValue))` compile?

Comment: My suggestion should have compiled. What was the compiler error?

Comment: @mjwills once i try your solution i get this error . Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestLager.Models.
StoragePlaces.ExternStoragePlace>'to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestLager.Models.StoragePlaces.PalletPlace>'

Comment: @Magnetron it doesnt compile cause of this error

Comment: Error CS1061 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a 
first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @Magnetron

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess here, but I remember having had problems with null coalescing in some Linq to SQL queries. I recommend you to try to declare your ids array as this :

```
int?[] ids = ViewModelsUtils.processIDs(IDs);
```

(use `int?[]`instead of `int[]` so this will match the type of your field)

Not sure about this, first because it doesn't seem to match the compilation error message, and secondly because I don't have a way to test this for the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue while using Delegates[] and used to get the `CS1929: 'Delegate?[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'`

Just included the `System.Linq` namespace and works fine now.