# Is there a way to loop through a List of strings against a database value in C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am querying results from the database. I have a column called **Extension** which can either be a gif, txt, docx etc. I am using Linq and Entity Framework Core. The extension is provided by a user or anyone searching and I understand I can just add multiple OR to my query but I have made a list of strings like below:

```
            List<string> ImageFormats = new List<string>();
            ImageFormats.Add("png");
            ImageFormats.Add("jpg");
            ImageFormats.Add("jpeg");
            ImageFormats.Add("tiff");
            ImageFormats.Add("gif");
```

Now I can add multiple OR statements to my query like below:

```
            var results = _database.Documents
                .Where(d => d.Extension == "png" || d.Extension == "png")
                .ToList();
```

But I want a different approach where I can use my list of extensions above on the query like below:

```
            var results = _database.Documents
                  .Where(d => d.Extension == ImageFormats)
                  .ToList();
```

Yes the code above cannot work. Is there a way something like this can be achieved?

Comment: `.Where(d => ImageFormats.Contains(d.Extension))`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if list contains item from other list in EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641016/check-if-list-contains-item-from-other-list-in-entityframework)

Comment: Maybe an "INNER JOIN" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really looks like you just want to use the `.Contains` method:

```
List<string> ImageFormats = new List<string>();
ImageFormats.Add("png");
ImageFormats.Add("jpg");
ImageFormats.Add("jpeg");
ImageFormats.Add("tiff");
ImageFormats.Add("gif");

var results = _database.Documents
                       .Where(d => ImageFormats.Contains(d.Extension))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: @codeninja Don't forget to mark this as the answer then, by pressing the checkmark button.

Comment: If you are using that LINQ on an `IQueryable` connected to TSQL backend, that should get composed into something like `WHERE [Extension] IN ('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'tiff', 'gif')`

Comment: I ddnt know this was possible without using so many OR's